# Update view background in post action Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to update an elements background image when a controller action is called and haven't been able to figure it out. In my view I have the following tag

```
<%= link_to '', color_animal_path(@article), method: :post, :id => "animal-image", remote: true %>
```

When it's clicked it calls the method below in my AnimalsController.rb

```
  def color
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {}
    end
    puts 'color called'
  end
```

I have a js file called color.js with the following contents in app/assets/javascripts

```
$('#animal-image').css('background-image', 'url("green.jpg")');
```

And the css for the element looks like this

```
#animal-image {
  float: left;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: grey;
  background: url('red.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

The view renders correctly with the red image, and clicking on the image calls the controller (I can see the puts output) however the element background image isn't updating...I'm hoping someone can help, am I on the right track, am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Is anything happening with the background on click at all? I am just wondering if the path to the image might need tweaking?

Comment: No background change at all, still displays original image...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a particular reason for the UJS call at all? Why not do this all in client-side jQuery?

Even if there is a reason (e.g. the colour needs to be dynamically set by the server, or you want to track the event), I'd suggest testing it in isolation on the client side until you get it working - then reintegrate the Rails UJS component.

For example, start with adding a new CSS class for the green image:

```
#animal-image.updated {
  background-image: url('green.png');
}
```

Then add some JS:

```
$( "#animal-image" ).click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('updated');
});
```

If that all works, then you can put it all back into `color.js` and then verify in your browser's dev tools that the response is coming back correctly and it's being evaluated.

Comment: This is a great idea and worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Quick follow up question if you have a sec. I'm rendering the link above inside of a partial so I have multiple rendering to the view. The js is only targeting the first (changes the first, clicks on all others change the first image). How can I make it so that it changes the correct partial?

Comment: @eclipse1203: does that mean you're reusing the same `id` in the HTML multiple times? If so, that might explain your original problem. ids should be unique within an HTML document, so try adding something to each iteration to make it unique e.g. at the most basic level you could append the `@article` id to the `id` name. Or you may be better off making it a class?

Comment: Ok so yes I was using the same id...good catch. I appended the article id to id element so it's unique and now in the controller method color I can get the value by @id = params[:id]. How can I pass this value into color.js? My color js file is $("#animal-image").toggleClass('updated');  I'm calling the js with the respond_to call I have in the first post, FYI

Comment: You'd have to amend `color_animal_path` to pass it in, and then pick up the `params` value in the controller/view. BUT - if the logic is the same for each element, I'd use `class` instead of `id`. Then it should be straightforward, and not need any changes.

Comment: Won't that cause the same issue since the animals all have the same class name initially?

Comment: Nope. `$(this)` in jQuery will distinguish between them. It wasn't working for `id` because it expects ids to be unique... and was simply returning the first instance it came across.

Comment: Awesome, that does work. How can I get it to work with respond_to? Here's a gist with what I have.